# Is there a database of book/movie character descriptions

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, text, books

For a machine learning task, I want to use book character descriptions to learn the possible properties of people of characters. Does anyone know a database of descriptions of book/movie characters? Real-life descriptions of people are also a possibility.